# Rust Lifetime Management Issue in Embedded Application

Tags: rust, slice, rust-cargo, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm working on an embedded Rust application where memory management is crucial. To minimize memory usage and avoid unnecessary cloning, I'm utilizing slices to read constants. However, I'm encountering a lifetime management issue that I can't seem to resolve.

The core of my problem lies in a function that's supposed to update some settings in a struct.

```
pub struct Decision_2<'a> {
    last_value: &'a [u8],
    temp_values: Vec<u8>, 
}
//
impl<'a> Decision_2<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            last_value: &DEFAULT_VALUE, // constant array of length 32
            temp_values: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn update(
        &mut self,
        current_index: &u8,
        all_values: &[AllValues], //struct of 2 field: index and cost
        flag_1: bool,
        flag_2: bool,
    ) -> &[u8] {
        let current_value: &[u8];

        if flag_1 {
            current_value = self.last_value;
        } else if *current_index != 70
            {
            self.temp_values.clear();
            
            for value in all_values.iter() {
                if value.index == *current_index  {
                    self.temp_values.push(value.cost);
                }
            }

            current_value = &self.temp_values;
        } else if *current_index == 10 {
            current_value = &DEFAULT_VALUE_1; //constant array of length 32
        } else if *current_index == 11
            || flag_2 {
            current_value = self.last_value;
        } else {
            current_value = &DEFAULT_VALUE;
        }

        self.last_value = current_value;

        self.last_value
    }
}
```

The error: error: lifetime may not live long enough

impl<'a> Decision_2<'a> {
-- lifetime `'a` defined here

```
    &mut self,
    - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`

        current_value = &self.temp_values;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
```

When I try this `pub fn update(&'a mut self...`, I get no compiler error, but I cannot loop over update anymore.

Comment: You're trying to store a reference to `self.temp_values` in `self.last_value`, that's not easily possible.